# My setup.py can't define the script when I try to install it

Tags: python

I've been trying to learn Python via *"Learn Python the Hard Way"*, and in ex46 he told us to put a script in bin and install it with `setup.py`.

My script's name was `testscript3.py`:

```python
from test3 import printstring

printstring.printstring("this is a test")
```

`test3.py` was like that:

```python
def printstring(s='you did not provide string'):
    print s
```

After making them I added the script to the `setup.py`:

```python
'scripts': [bin/testscript3.py],
```

and in PowerShell I wrote:

```bsh
python setup.py install
```

in order to install it, but I got an error:

> testscript3 is not defined

I tried to import it by doing:

```python
from bin import testscript3
```

but still getting the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a string in your setup.py The reason you're getting `testscript3 is not defined` is because without the quotes around `bin/testscript3.py` Python expects `bin/testscript3.py` to be a variable.

```
'scripts': ['bin/testscript3.py'],
```

Comment: Precisely - it tries to do _division_ between two objects, `bin` and `testscript3.py`, where `testscript3.py` is simply `py` attribute of object assigned to name `testscript3`. To resolve operator overloading it need to check type of both arguments. Trying to resolve a type of RHS argument fails.